# Write a program that uses a for-loop to iterate through this array, displaying the values stored at every index

Tags: c

I have written a small program that holds an array of 10 numbers, I wish for the output of the program to look like this:

```
Index  Value
0      2
1      4
2      6
3      8
4      10
5      12
6      14
7      16
8      18
9      20
```

However I do not know how to make my code do that. This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};  // 10 elements
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<(&a)[1]-a; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: How does the output relate to the contents of the array?  It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: `(&a)[1]-a` this construct should definitely not be there.

Comment: i need the program to print the index number of the array and what is stored in the array for that index in a vertical column for each with index and value above

Comment: @dbush i have edited the question now to show

Comment: @EugeneSh. i have edited the question now to show what i need

Comment: So how exactly the code presented is supposed to achieve that? It looks totally random to me.

Comment: Have you tried printing the index and the value on a single line each time through the loop?

Comment: @dbush i dont know how to do that

Comment: @EugeneSh. when the code is compiled and ran it prints the array in a line

Comment: You're already printing the value.  Just print the index first, then print a newline after the value.

Comment: Okay then how do i print them vertically

Comment: You can't print "veritically".  You print a line at a time. Don't overthink it.

Comment: @dbush okay i think i get you now

Comment: I think this should be closed as being as trivial as possible. Any text book on C will answer this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach how you could do it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    int a[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};  // 10 elements

    printf("Index\tValue\n");

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\t%d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Press any key to continue . . .\n");  
    getchar();  

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: You beat me to an answer by 9 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

`(&a)[1]-a` is not good syntax or what you want to do here. I believe this would get the address of `a`, add 1, and subtract the address of `a`, so you would end up with a value of 1. This will make your `for` loop run only once. You want it to run as many times as there are values in your array so that it prints each value in it.

Make a global constant of the length of the array, and use that. I used `LEN`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define LEN 10

int main()
{
    int a[LEN] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};  // 10 elements
    int i;

    // Header
    printf("Index\tValue");

    for(i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        printf("%d\t%d\n", i, a[i]); // `\n` newline to print next values on next line

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```